# Crystal report asking sql credentials every time in sage erp

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I create a crystal report using sql commands when it run it works fine.But after i pasted it to the SAGE ERP when i try to run it asks for SQL Cerdential every time. Please help me to sort out this issue and how to stop the credential for the reports.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

See under what username the Sage ERP runs and give that user permissions to access the SQL database.. It sounds like a permissions issue in the SQL database.

Comment: Yeah, But when i execute report in the server itself asking credential for SQL.But other reports working fine, this is the one makes problem when running. For the report i created a ODBC connection, but still facing the same issue